# Is an else always necessary in java?

Tags: java, if-statement

```
class ChangeCase{
  public static void main(String args[])
    throws java.io.IOException{
    char response;
    int count = 0;
    System.out.println("You can keep feeding me input. Enter a period to stop me.");
    do{
      response = (char) System.in.read();
      if(response != '\r' & response != '\n') {
        if(response >= 65 & response <= 90) {

          response = (char) (response + 32);
          count++;
        }
        if(response >= 97 & response <= 122) {

          response = (char) (response - 32);
          count++;
        }
        System.out.print(response);
      }
      if(response == '\n') System.out.print('\n');
    } while(response != '.');
    System.out.println("\n" + count);
  }
}
```

When I make one change to this code by putting "else " before the second if statement the code works the way I want it to. It spits out the user's input. It changes uppercase to lowercase and vice versa. But as is it fails to change uppercase to lowercase. I want to know why.

Comment: With the `else`, it will only execute 1 of the clauses; which ever is true first. Without it, it will execute any that are true.

Comment: I guess you are wanting to use `&&` not `&`

Comment: @Joseph Guzman : this is Happening because. both if conditions are executing in case of Capital letter. e.g. You type 'A'. first if will execute and your response is 'a' after conversion. but this response 'a' is also valid for second if statement. So it again convert it to capital 'A'. I suggest use else if here.

Comment: @ScaryWombat:  The bitwise AND *works* enough; yes, the OP probably intended to use the logical AND, but in this case it just means that both sides get evaluated instead of short-circuiting.

Comment: Just so you know, you shouldn't put your answer in your question.  The answer section below is for that.  If an answer helped you, accept it.  If you have your own answer, add it.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking at is an `else-if` construct.

In your case, both `if` statements will always be evaluated. However, when you add the `else`, the second statement will only ever be evaluated once if the first evaluates to `false`

Comment: @Carcigenicate I was using it show the idea behind the construct not the actual code.

Comment: Ahh, makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't put `else` it executes both `if`s. First changing to upper case then to lowercase. You want either-or not both.

Comment: Okay thanks, so my code here is changing the case twice.

Comment: Yes it goes forward then back to where you started.

Answer (score 0):

Two consecutive `if` statements will execute if both of their conditions are valid for execution.  That's the simplest and least ambiguous part of this problem.

*Because* you're mutating the data used to test your condition, ***both*** `if` statements will execute.  *This* is the more complicated and nuanced problem you're trying to solve.

A simple debug will expose this:

- `'A'` is entered.  It meets the first `if` statement's condition and is immediately lower-cased (by adding 32 to the character), resulting in `'a'`.
- `'a'` is tested by the immediately following `if` statement - since the variable `response` is changed, and it of course meets that requirement as well.  In response, the character is immediately upper-cased (by subtracting 32 from the character), resulting in `'A'`.

Now, if you stop the execution of your application, you'll get 2 instead of 1, due to the way you're counting the interactions within the `if` blocks.

The mitigation *could* be to add an `else` to your second `if`, but I'm not so sure that it'd be the *best* approach.  You can also introduce a new variable to the equation to ensure that no mutation of your input ever occurs, which would be more ideal.

```
class ChangeCase {
    public static void main(String args[])
            throws java.io.IOException {
        char response;
        char result = '\0'; // This holds the result now
        int count = 0;
        System.out.println("You can keep feeding me input. Enter a period to stop me.");
        do {
            response = (char) System.in.read();
            if (response != '\r' & response != '\n') {
                if (response >= 65 & response <= 90) {

                    result = (char) (response + 32);
                    count++;
                }
                if (response >= 97 & response <= 122) {

                    result = (char) (response - 32);
                    count++;
                }
                System.out.print(result);
            }
            if (response == '\n') {
                System.out.print('\n');
            }
        } while (response != '.');
        System.out.println("\n" + count);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Option 1
if(response >= 65 & response <= 90) {

  response = (char) (response + 32);
  System.out.print(response);
  count++;
  continue;
}
if(response >= 97 & response <= 122) {

  response = (char) (response - 32);
  System.out.print(response);
  count++;
  continue;
}


// Option 2
if(response >= 65 & response <= 90) {

  response = (char) (response + 32);
  count++;
}else if(response >= 97 & response <= 122) {

  response = (char) (response - 32);
  count++;
}
System.out.print(response);
```